# Getting exception while running Executable jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java, exception, jar

I am getting errors when trying to run the jar from Eclipse. It is working fine when running from the windows command prompt. However, while trying to run from Java source code it shows the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
    at edu.ucla.cs.examplecheck.utils.PatternUtils.loadPattern(PatternUtils.java:37)
    at edu.ucla.cs.examplecheck.APIMisuseDetector.main(APIMisuseDetector.java:48)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: looks like the dependency libraries are not in the class path of the Runtime Execution environment of Eclipse

Comment: I checked the libraries in the classpath. Looks like it's okay. Any other thoughts? @pradoshnair

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not able to locate jar for  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

If you are using maven, gradle then may be you can try adding dependency of "  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils " in pom.xml or build.gradle.

Comment: Added the following dependency to pom.xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
unfortunately, no luck.